# iPhone UITableView scrolling same time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have 2 table view, with the same number of cells.
Could you please point me the correct way, that I could implement simultaneous scrolling. I mean, when I scroll through one table, the other one is scrolling the same time. Thanks.

Comment: How are the two tableViews positioned and what do you want to achieve? Can you elaborate a little? I think with a little more details we should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As uitable view is derived from uiscrollview you can get the scroll amounts in the delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

You can get content offset of the scrollview which is being scrolled and assign that to the other tableview.

In this method you should be able to access both tableviews.

The property you need to check is `contentOffset`.

`firsttableview.contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset`

Comment: You have to make the content offsets of both the table views same basically. So this delegate method gives you content offset. Now make first and second tableview content offset equal. firsttableview.contentoffset =  secondtableview.contentoffset.